# outer async context manager finalized before inner async generator

Tags: python, python-asyncio, playwright-python

Given the following minimal example:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def async_context():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('finalize context')


async def async_gen():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        # will never be called if timeout is larger than in async_context
        print('finalize gen')


async def main():
    async with async_context():
        async for _ in async_gen():
            break


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I'm `break`ing while iterating over the async generator and I want the finally block to complete before my async context manager `finally` block runs. In this example `"finalize gen"` will never be printed because the program exits before that happens.

Note that I intentionally chose a timeout of `2` in the generators `finally` block so the context managers `finally` has a chance to run before. If I chose `1` for both timeouts both messages will be printed.

Is this kind of a race condition? I expected all `finally` blocks to complete before the program finishes.

**How can I prevent the context mangers `finally` block to run before the generators `finally` block has completed?**

For context:

I use [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/) to control a chromium browser. The outer context manager provides a page that it closes in the `finally` block.

I'm using python `3.9.0`.

Try this example: https://repl.it/@trixn86/AsyncGeneratorRaceCondition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The async context manager doesn't know anything about the asynchronous generator. Nothing in `main` knows about the asynchronous generator after you `break`, in fact. You've given yourself no way to wait for the generator's finalization.

If you want to wait for the generator to close, you need to handle closure explicitly:

```
async def main():
    async with async_context():
        gen = async_gen()
        try:
            async for _ in gen:
                break
        finally:
            await gen.aclose()
```

In Python 3.10, you'll be able to use `contextlib.aclosing` instead of the try/finally:

```
async def main():
    async with async_context():
        gen = async_gen()
        async with contextlib.aclosing(gen):
            async for _ in gen:
                break
```